# Длина массива в функции с++

Tags: c++

Как можно в теле функции узнать длину передаваемого массива (для тела цикла)?

```
#include <iostream>

int myfunc(int arr[])
{
    int sum=0, quantity=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (длина массива (указателя)); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            quantity++;
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
   int a[70], b[80], c[65];
   std::cout << myfunc(a);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` не подошёл?

Comment: @pavel если Вы о sizeof(mas)/sizeof(mas[0]), то нет, не подошел

Comment: C и C++ это разные языки. Впредь, пожалуйста, выбирайте один тег

Comment: Предполагается использовать только массивы, размер которых известен на момент компиляции?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ваш вопрос настолько популярен, что попал даже в FAQ по языку C: [[1]](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html), [[2]](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html).

Дело в том, что в параметрах функций массивы «превращаются» в указатели. Поэтому ваше объявление функции ничем не отличается от

```
int myfunc(int* arr)
```

Вы можете проверить, что в вашей функции `sizeof(arr)` даёт размер указателя (на современных архитектурах обычно 4 или 8).

Практический выход: передавайте длину массива отдельным параметром.

Comment: В си++ не обязательно так. Можно размер массива упихать в аргумент шаблона, как делает `std::end`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: в C++ можно просто использовать `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

В Си никак.

В Си++ можно использовать шаблонную функцию, в которой размер станет параметром шаблона. В любом случае, так не стоит делать, т. к. это не позволит использовать функцию с динамическими массивами.

http://ideone.com/HNxwr8

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename typed, size_t n> void f(typed (&a)[n])
{
    for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
        cout << a[q] << ' ';

    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    char s[] = "Just a string";
    double b[] = {1.5, 2.75, 4};

    f(a);
    f(b);
    f(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В C тоже можно, через указатель на массив. Как и в C++ через ссылку, без шаблона.

Comment: @ixSci, но без шаблонов придётся руками копипастить (ну или дефайнить) по функции на каждый размер. Да ещё под разными именами, т. к. перегрузки там тоже нет.

Comment: Я не говорил, что это удобно :) Просто так можно сделать, вот и всё. А у Вас написано, что в C это никак не сделать, что формально неверно.

Comment: @ixSci, но это будет не одна функция (впрочем, шаблонная после компиляции тоже не будет одной), и выбирать между функциями придётся программисту, а не компилятору. Так что это совсем не то.

Answer (score 4):

В теле функции вы можете узнать длинну массива из передаваемого по соседству аргумента:

```
int foo(int *buffer, const size_t bufferSize) {...}
```

Интересней же вопрос о том **как возвращать массив из функции**. Для этих целей в C++11 появился `std::array`, который является ничем иным, как оберткой над обычными статическими буферами, которая, среди прочего, содержит метод size().

Comment: А зачем пометили `bufferSize` как `const`?

Comment: @ixSci подчеркиваю семантику переменной.

Comment: @free_ze тогда почему не `int * const buffer`? :)

Comment: @alexolut можно и так. Вас не смущает, что точки стоят в теле функции?)

Comment: @free_ze Если Вы хотите сказать, что `...` подразумевают возможность изменять данные по указателю, то при `int * const buffer` это тоже будет возможно (это же не `const int * buffer`). Но при этом остается единообразность при подчеркивании семантики переменной. Как нельзя изменить `bufferSize`, так нельзя изменить и `buffer`.

Comment: @alexolut Нет, я так игриво указываю на ваше буквоедство) Ошибки здесь нет и такой код кажется мне эстетичнее.

Comment: @free_ze ошибки не будет и при отсутствии 'const' у длины. Но Вы же настраиваете на семантике. Поэтому, логично было бы распространить это на все аргументы функции.

Comment: @alexolut Я не настаиваю, а обосновываю. Идите своей дорогой)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант - использовать vector и получать размер массива с помощью `arr.size()`

Comment: тогда лучше `std::array`, вектор это динамический массив.

Comment: @ixSci `std::array` не позволит передавать в функцию массивы разной длины.

Comment: @alexolut, добавить шаблон и будет принимать.

Comment: @ixSci шаблон породит уже семейство функций.

Comment: @alexolut, какая разница для пользователя функции?

Comment: @ixSci например, придется предоставить исходный код для такого пользователя. Просто если задача в том чтобы единообразно обрабатывать массивы различной длины, то `std::array` тут явно нельзя назвать лучшим решением. А если размер меняется в рантайме, то `std::array` вообще не подойдет.

Comment: @alexolut, вопрос про C-подобный массив, причём тут динамика? Автору нужен массив постоянного размера и `std::array` полностью отражает эту нужду, тогда как `std::vector`, помимо того, что является более «тяжёлым» ещё и имеет побочные функции, которые не нужны тогда, когда нужен массив постоянного размера.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с данной проблемой сегодня, но всё-таки нашёл выход.
Длинну массива можно определить с помощью такой функции:

```
int getLength(char text[]){
    int arrayLength=0;
    for(int i=0;text[i];i++){
        arrayLength++;
    }
    return arrayLength;
}

int main(void){
cout<<getLength("Symbols");
}
```

Также для возврата массива в функцию достаточно написать
`char *` перед названием функции.

Comment: Нет. У вас в функции делается определение длины С-строки, а не длины массива. Длина строки никакого отношения к длине передаваемого массива в общем случае не имеет. О каком "возврате массива в функцию" вы ведете речь и при чем он здесь - не ясно. Это не говоря уже о том, что на вопросе стоит тег [C++], а в С++ передавать строковый литерал `"Symbols"` как `char *` уже давно запрещено.